# Mostrar valores de columna de mysql en imput text sin introducir ningún dígito

Tags: php, mysql, select2

Tengo un ejemplo funcionando de auto completado, al introducir un dígito en el imput text "nombrecli_1" se inicia una búsqueda en la base de datos el la columna "nombrecli" y muestra un desplegable con las coincidencias. Una vez seleccionas una de las opciones se auto completan otros imput text tomando como referencia el id. 
He intentado modificar el ejemplo para que muestre el desplegable  sin tener que pulsar ningún dígito, en el formulario final el usuario puede no tener ni idea que de los resgistros de la columna clientes.

Al no poder modificar el ejemplo he intentado substituir el imput text por un select con la librería select2. Esta librería me ha permitido conectar con la base de datos y mostrar mediante desplegable todos los resultados de la columna sin tener que introducir ningún dígito.

Pensaba que ya había encontrado la solución, pero no soy capaz de hacer converger los dos ejemplos. Cuando selecciono la opción en el desplegable del select (id = nombrecli_1) no se me auto completa el imput text (id = telefonocli_1)

Realmente necesitaría poder modificar la opción con el imput text ya querría que el usuario pudiera introducir valores que no estén en la database y se crearan al enviar el form, pero esto puedo trampear lo haciendo otro form para la creación de nuevos registros.

Os agradecería si pudierais revisar el código.

Muchas gracias

Index.html ( he dejado las dos opciones (imput text y select)

```
<html>
        <head>
            <title>Webslesson Demo - Dynamically Add or Remove input fields in PHP with JQuery</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <link href='jquery-ui.min.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' >
            <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">

            <!-- select2 css -->
            <link href='select2/dist/css/select2.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

            <!-- select2 script -->
            <script src='select2/dist/js/select2.min.js'></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){

                $(document).on('keypress', '.nombrecli', function() {

                    var id = this.id;
                    var splitid = id.split('_');
                    var index = splitid[1];

                    $( '#'+id ).autocomplete({
                        source: function( request, response ) {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "getDetails.php",
                                type: 'post',
                                dataType: "json",
                                data: {
                                    search: request.term,request:1
                                },
                                success: function( data ) {
                                    response( data );
                                }
                            });
                        },
                        select: function (event, ui) {
                            $(this).val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
                            var userid = ui.item.value; // selected id to input

                            // AJAX
                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'getDetails.php',
                                type: 'post',
                                data: {userid:userid,request:2},
                                dataType: 'json',
                                success:function(response){

                                    var len = response.length;

                                    if(len > 0){
                                        var idcli = response[0]['idcli'];
                                        var namecli = response[0]['nombrecli'];
                                        var telefonocli = response[0]['telefonocli'];


                                        document.getElementById('nombrecli_'+index).value = namecli;
                                        document.getElementById('telefonocli_'+index).value = telefonocli;


                                    }

                                }
                            });

                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                });


            });



        </script>


        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <br />
                <br />
                <h2 align="center"><a href="http://www.webslesson.info/2016/02/dynamically-add-remove-input-fields-in-php-with-jquery-ajax.html" title="Dynamically Add or Remove input fields in PHP with JQuery">Dynamically Add or Remove input fields in PHP with JQuery</a></h2><br />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <form name="add_name" id="add_name"> 
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_fieldcli">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>CLIENTE: <input type="text" name="nombrecli_1" placeholder="Enter your Name" id='nombrecli_1' class="nombrecli" class="form-control name_list" /></td> //
                                    <td>CLIENTE: <select  name="nombrecli_1" placeholder="Enter your Name" id='nombrecli_1' class="nombrecli" class="form-control name_list" style='width: 200px;'>
                                        <option value='0'>- Search user -</option>
                                    </select></td>
                                    <td>TELEFONO: <input type="text" name="telefonocli[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" id='telefonocli_1' class="telefonocli" /></td>

                                    <td><button type="button" name="add" id="addcli" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>

                                </tr>

                            </table>
                        </div>



                    </form>
                </div>





        </body>
    </html>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var i=1;
        $('#addcli').click(function(){
            i++;
            $('#dynamic_fieldcli').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="nombrecli_'+i+'" id="nombrecli_'+i+'" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="nombrecli" /></td><td><input type="text" name="telefonocli[]" id="telefonocli_'+i+'" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="telefonocli" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
        });


        $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
            i--;
            var button_id = $(this).attr("id"); 
            $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
        });



    });



            $(document).ready(function(){

                $("#nombrecli_1").select2({
                    ajax: {
                        url: "getData.php",
                        type: "post",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        delay: 250,
                        data: function (params) {
                            return {
                                searchTerm: params.term // search term
                            };
                        },
                        processResults: function (response) {
                            return {
                                results: response
                            };
                        },
                        cache: true
                    }
                });
            });
    </script>
```

getdetails.php

```
<?php
    include "config.php";

    $request = $_POST['request'];   // request

    // Get username list
    if($request == 1){
        $search = $_POST['search'];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE nombrecli like'%".$search."%'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
            $response[] = array("value"=>$row['idcli'],"label"=>$row['nombrecli']);
        }

        // encoding array to json format
        echo json_encode($response);
        exit;
    }

    // Get details
    if($request == 2){
        $userid = $_POST['userid'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE idcli=".$userid;

        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

        $users_arr = array();

        while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
            $userid = $row['idcli'];
            $nombrecli = $row['nombrecli'];
            $telefonocli = $row['telefonocli'];


            $users_arr[] = array("idcli" => $userid, "nombrecli" => $nombrecli, "telefonocli" => $telefonocli);
        }

        // encoding array to json format
        echo json_encode($users_arr);
        exit;
    }
```

getdata.php

```
<?php
    include 'config.php';

    if(!isset($_POST['searchTerm'])){
        $fetchData = mysqli_query($con,"select * from clientes order by nombrecli limit 5");
    }else{
        $search = $_POST['searchTerm'];
        $fetchData = mysqli_query($con,"select * from clientes where nombrecli like '%".$search."%' limit 5");
    }

    $data = array();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetchData)) {
        $data[] = array("id"=>$row['idcli'], "text"=>$row['nombrecli']);
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: si deseas hacer algo luego de que el usuario seleccione una opcion de tu select debes ejecutar una funcion mediante el evento onchange="miFuncion($(this).val());" con esto estas llamando a la funcion mifuncion para ejecutar tu consulta y traer valores con la seleccion del usuario

Comment: mas detalle aqui https://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solución 1:

Para la opción usando [`jQuery UI Autocomplete`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), solo debes establecer [`minLength`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-minLength) igual a cero.

> La cantidad mínima de caracteres que un usuario debe escribir antes de realizar una búsqueda. Cero es útil para datos locales con solo unos pocos elementos, pero se debe usar un valor más alto cuando la búsqueda de un solo caracter puede coincidir con unos pocos miles de elementos.

#### Ejemplo:

```
$('#' + id).autocomplete({
  minLength: 0, // <-- AQUI le indicamos que se despliegue sin esperar a que ingresen datos
  source: function(request, response) {...},
  select: ...
```

Comment: Apenas vuelva, agrego una solución para select2

Comment: Funcionando!! Muchas gracias Marcos. El script esta configurado para que inicie con keydown ($(document).on('keydown', '.nombrecli', function() )y es un sin sentido. He probado con las opciones "click" "focus" y "ready" pero no consigo que despliegue la lista de opciones